# What's the difference between the following two matrix define functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I met this problem when I was doing a Spiral Matrix problem. When I used B, each row of the matrix seems to refer to the same object as all the rows are the same. Whereas the A option works as expected. Why does this happen?

A. `let matrix = Array(n).fill(0).map(el => Array(n).fill(0));`

B. `let matrix = new Array(n).fill(new Array(n).fill(0));`

Comment: Ironically enough I just answered more-or-less this same exact question recently!

Answer (score 0):

In the `A` example you're creating a new array for each element to fill.
In the `B` you're creating an array once, then use this array while filling.